# How to Change Html Element Text Using

Tags: javascript, html, css

I hope I can make myself as clear as possible, I'm a real newbie when it comes to CSS and HTML, but I'm trying my best searching on the net.

I'm trying to translate a website using Google Inspect and save the changes on my pc. So far I've been able to do it using an extension called "Stylebot".

What I got so far is this:

```css
._35oZDD6pOLbfsDeSjB48Da h1 {
  display: none;
}

._35oZDD6pOLbfsDeSjB48Da:after {
  content: "Painel de Controle";
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 0;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #3c4858;
}
```

```html
<div class="_35oZDD6pOLbfsDeSjB48Da">
  <h1>Dashboard</h1>
  <div class="KnPkTluaZGwNajQrPdUXK title-help-wrapper">
    <div class="_1kb2R813ulFuiel2ebkDj3 title-help">
      <div class="_3Ow41suot3IX3Reh-6Xs4Y title-help-content">
        <div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And it worked perfectly fine.

But my question is: How can I edit the text "Dashboard" here:

```
<a data-test-id="nav-link-dashboard" class="_35y4mNBXV8raOLGtBvhTmr O6aRKDJKQc5N9t_-J7iyI" href="/fb1117682158281014/dashboard">
    <div class="row middle-xs p-y-sm">
        <div class="text-center _3eiyvN-y_YD9WeLYpjiJJO col-auto" style="flex: 0 0 65px; width: 65px;">
            <i class="i-dashboard"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="p-r-sm col-auto col-grow">
            <span class="uO-IdjD0GZlRnQ66I7sbe">
                <!-- react-text: 40 -->Dashboard<!-- /react-text -->
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

Is there a way to edit this, using CSS path? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You can **replace** text content in JavaScript with **[`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)**. You will first need to target the element, which I do in the following example with **[`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)**. Note that this returns a **[NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)** collection of elements, so you'll need to access the first index:

```js
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('uO-IdjD0GZlRnQ66I7sbe')[0];
element.innerHTML = 'Replaced';
```

```html
<span class="uO-IdjD0GZlRnQ66I7sbe">
<!-- react-text: 40 -->Dashboard<!-- /react-text -->
</span>
```

You **cannot** replace it with only CSS, as the **[`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content)** property only works with pseudo-selectors **[`:before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Abefore)** and **[`:after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Aafter)**. You could **add to it** in this regard.

```css
.uO-IdjD0GZlRnQ66I7sbe:after {
  content: '- Added';
}
```

```html
<span class="uO-IdjD0GZlRnQ66I7sbe">
<!-- react-text: 40 -->Dashboard<!-- /react-text -->
</span>
```

Hope this helps! :)